# Jackson Object Mapper class given an error Spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, jackson

Jackson Object Mapper class given an error Spring mvc

All required jar already added no error in project like jackson-core-asl, jackson-core-2.2.3 and jackson-all 1.9.0 still getting error

[image]

[image]

Comment: please add the entire error message which will help to understand the situation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our SO Question Checklist to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: I think spring already includes jackson jars

Comment: This is `Jackson 1` class, can you share all you external jars?

Comment: Try removing `jackson-all` from your class path and use Jackson 2 package path.`org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper -&gt; com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary `jackson-all` and `jackson-core-asl` dependencies.

Include the only one `jackson-databind` that automatically de/serializes the objects.

```
<jackson.version>2.8.9</jackson.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Don't forget to return the whole `List<Demo>` instead of String.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getJson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Demo> listJsonList {
    // ...
    return alldatalist;
}
```

And please, next time copy-paste the source code as a text, not as the image :)